# Where should system initialization methods be placed in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: android, iphone, windows, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've developed a number of applications using Cocos2d-x on the iOS platform.

I have always placed the loading of resources, preloading of audio, and initialization of system components into the AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() function, or had it call the initialization routine from there.  This was because this is the place where the first main scene for the application is selected and loaded into the CCDirector.

Recently, one of my tutorials was ported to Windows and it appears this was not being called. Perhaps it does not even exist in Android or other target platforms for cocos2d-x (I only deal with one for now).

Is there a common location across all platforms where cocos2d-x expect you to place the "Application Initialization" code?

Comment: applicationDidFinishLaunching is a particularly bad place to perform initialization, especially when loading resources is time-consuming. On iOS the watchdog may kill your app if it takes too long to return from the launch process (ie said method doesn't return quickly).

Comment: Good point.  Love your stuff...have your book.  Custom loading scene as best option?

Comment: Yup that's the way to go.